# iOS UI overlay library?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am looking for a way to have a overlay that looks similar to MB Progress HUD but to show some more content, like an image and some text with a button to close.  Not looking to use a bult in Modal view but something a little slicker and less bulky - kinda like a nice flat popover like you see in the Books app on the iPad.

I have been searching with no luck - anyone seen something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another alternative SGPopoverController at https://github.com/KJoyner/SeaGlass . This is similar to WEPopover but has more options behaving modally and non-modally within a view (or top-level window). In particular, this class supports passthroughViews and like MBProgressHUD can completely disable UI events outside the popover.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be what you're looking for?

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/wepopover

WEPopover is apparently a popover UI control for the iPhone that mimics the API of UIPopover on the iPad as close as possible.

If you want something that is a little closer to MBProgressHUD in terms of the transparent HUD style, you might try http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tapku-alerts-with-images

Tapku Alerts seem to be simple views that I'm sure you could hack around with a little bit and add your own buttons too.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to build yourself if a given library is unsatisfactory: a full-screen 0.0 opacity view to absorb touches in front of which is your visible overlay view with whatever controls you want is straightforward. If your animation is limited to the basic Core Animation stuff -- position, size, rotation, opacity, and view/control properties like color, etc. -- then displaying it and removing it is easy. Only if you want fancy animation does it get tricky.